# Android Compress a Bitmap

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I have wrote this method before I noticed there is a compress method in Bitmap class.

```
/**
 * Calcuate how much to compress the image
 * @param options
 * @param reqWidth
 * @param reqHeight
 * @return
 */
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1; // default to not zoom image

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
             final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height/ (float) reqHeight);
             final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
             inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }
        return inSampleSize;
}

/**
 * resize image to 480x800
 * @param filePath
 * @return
 */
public static Bitmap getSmallBitmap(String filePath) {

    File file = new File(filePath);
    long originalSize = file.length();

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize based on a preset ratio
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 480, 800);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    Bitmap compressedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);


    return compressedImage;
}
```

I was wondering, compare to the built in `Compress` method, should I keep using this one, or switch to use the built in one? what is the difference?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156501/what-is-the-difference-between-compressing-image-and-resizing-image-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is in line with [Loading Large Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) guidelines

- Large file on disk
- Small bitmap in memory

compress() methods converts a large bitmap to a small one:

- Large bitmap in memory
- Small bitmap on disk (IOStream) (and possibly in different format)

I would use your method if I needed to load bitmap from a file to ImageViews of different sizes.

Comment: Hmmm, actually I just did some test, and it looks like my code will not reduce the map

Comment: May be your bitmap is small enough already?  Also, your calculateInSampleSize() is missing an iteration loop.  Just copy&paste Google's code as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

`Basically`

What you are doing in the above code is just resizing the image ,which will not loose much of the quality of the image since you use the `SampleSize` .

`compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality, OutputStream stream)`

It is used when you want to change the `imageFormat` you have `Bitmap.CompressFormat JPEG`
`Bitmap.CompressFormat  PNG` `Bitmap.CompressFormat WEBP` or to reduce the `quality` of the image using the `quality` parameter `0 - 100` .